# Nuxt Firebase using where

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js

I am trying to return documents from firebase using nuxt firebase and need to include a where but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.$fireModule.firestore.FieldPath.assess is not a function. (In 'this.$fireModule.firestore.FieldPath.assess()', 'this.$fireModule.firestore.FieldPath.assess' is undefined)
```

From what I read I have to use this.$firemodule but still not working for me

My code is as follows:

```
this.$fire.firestore.collection('lights')
    .where(this.$fireModule.firestore.FieldPath.assess(), '==', 'ZxBc9dMxVdodbHtnAf5g')
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {...
```

I have enabled functions in my Nuxt.config.js

Answer (score 1):

Overcomplicated it

```
.where('assess', '==', this.$route.params.id)
    .get()
```

works